# python: taking random sample from data but keeping the same distribution

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a training data that has 20,000 and more instances, split into 3 classes, with a distribution like A=10%, B=20%, C=70%. Is there a way in sklearn or pandas or anything else that can take a sample of 10% from this data but at the same time respecting the distribution of different classes? As I need do grid search on the data but the original dataset is too high dimensional (20,000 x 12,000 feature dimension)

The train_test_split will keep the distribution but it only splits the entire dataset into two sets, which are still too large.

Thanks

Comment: why not use `train_test_split` with `test_size` of 0.1 then operate on that 0.1 of data you get ? not the best solution but the simplest i think

Comment: If you just pick 10% of the data randomly, then you should end up with the same distribution (small variations at most).

The bigger the number of data points, the closer to the original distribution you should get. Taking 2000 out of 20000 should already get you very close to the same distribution, without having to do any cherry-picking.

Comment: You can use `train_test_split` along with the `stratify` parameter to obtain a single split instead of multiple splits as in StratifiedKFold.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [Stratifiefkfold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html). The folds are made by preserving the percentage of samples for each class.
See the documentation for using it.

Answer (score 1):

The train_test_split function allows a definition of the size of the training data:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.1)
```

[See the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html)